# Use a moving div as a CSS clip path

Tags: javascript, html, css, clip, clip-path

I cannot seem to find a similar question out there in Google nor Stack Overflow. Here is my situation.

I have a div being used for a background image. I want this image to be hidden except for what is behind a second div that moves around with the mouse.

The moving div is a 250px by 250px circle like this.

```
<div class="page-mouse-tail"></div>
<style>
.page-mouse-tail {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
</style>
```

I move that div around using this Javascript:

```
"use strict";
var mouseTails = document.getElementsByClassName("page-mouse-tail");
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(mouseTails, function (tail) {
        tail.style.left = event.pageX + "px";
        tail.style.top = event.pageY + "px";
    });
});
```

Is there anyway I can make it so the background-image div can only be seen by what is "underneath" the mouse-tail div? Like a clip-path that is a circle, but moves with the mouse. I would like to only use CSS and Javascript, if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to the second div's style:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes by applying a giant `box-shadow` to your "page-tail" div

```js
"use strict";
var mouseTails = document.getElementsByClassName("page-mouse-tail");
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(mouseTails, function(tail) {
    tail.style.left = event.pageX + "px";
    tail.style.top = event.pageY + "px";
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: url(http://wallpaper.ouzs.com/wallpapers/windows_dual_monitor2880x900.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
.page-mouse-tail {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  /* for demo */
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 9999px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-mouse-tail"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this creative solution. Do you have an idea of the performance hit that the giant box-shadow might make? When I tried this code, if I made the box-shadow too big it just wouldn't render.

Comment: I don't I confess,. I suppose you could use 100vw instead which might make it smaller and so more performant but there's a lot of screen repainting going on but that's probably the limits of a CSS solution.